# Rails - Save object where one field does not come from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So here is my problem:

I need to create an identifier for an order. I already have an ID field, but they wanted to create an identifier based on the date and time the order is created.

I created the migration, and added the identifier with no problems, but i need to generate this identifier at the controller create method and save the order. Something like this:

```
def create
    identifier = generate_identifier
    @order = Order.new(order_params, identifier)
    if @order.save
      OrderMailer.confirm_order_email(@order, current_user).deliver
    else
      flash[:errors] = @order.errors.full_messages
      errors_user_logged?
    end
  end
```

How can i call Order.new with order_params along with the generated identifier?

Comment: Use 'before_create' callback to generate identifier for each order in order.rb file. Checkout this link for details: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to move this down to the model layer. This doesn't seem like a concern of the controller. You can define a method or two in the model and use a `before_create` callback to do this. It should make testing easier as well.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_identifier

  private

  def set_identifier
    self.identifier = generate_identifier
  end

  def generate_identifier
    # code to generate the identifier
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

How about inserting `identifier` in`params` as follows?

```
def create
  params[:order][:identifier] = generate_identifier
  @order = Order.new(order_params)
  if @order.save
    OrderMailer.confirm_order_email(@order, current_user).deliver
  else
    flash[:errors] = @order.errors.full_messages
    errors_user_logged?
  end
end


def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:something, :something, :identifier)
end
```

Comment: It will work but appending application generated value to params is not a good way to do it. if you need this entire params again for some other purpose you would have to remove or use `.except` method in order to ignore `identifier`

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I see ! As you say, I noticed that changing params directly isn't good. @Abhinay